# A shortcut for IP address in the DNS zone config file

Tags: bind, dns-zone, domain-name-system

A question about DNS zone files syntax (not sure if it's correct term here).

For my dedicated server I have the following zone file right now:

```
$TTL 86400
@   IN SOA ns1.first-ns.de. postmaster.robot.first-ns.de. (
    2013111400   ; serial
    14400        ; refresh
    1800         ; retry
    604800       ; expire
    86400 )      ; minimum

@                        IN NS      ns1.first-ns.de.
@                        IN NS      robotns2.second-ns.de.
@                        IN NS      robotns3.second-ns.com.

@                        IN A       144.76.184.151
localhost                IN A       127.0.0.1
www                      IN A       144.76.184.151
@                        IN MX 100  afarber.de.
```

And I wonder if the 2 lines (which use the same IP-address on the right side) could be written in a shorter form?

```
@                        IN A       144.76.184.151
www                      IN A       144.76.184.151
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly shorter but you can change the 'www' record to a CNAME over an A record. If you set it to a CNAME of your base domain, you will only have to update the primary A record for both to be changed.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean `www CNAME afarber.de.`?

Comment: I'm not actually sure, as I haven't used bind before. Just copy the rest of the syntax, which looks like it would be 'www IN CNAME afarber.de.'

Comment: Peter is right. It is common to use `www IN CNAME @` in Bind. Just copy paste that as a replacement to 'www IN A 144.76.184.151'